# Multiply 128-bit vectors of signed 16-bit integers, widening to 32-bit elements

Tags: sse, intrinsics

I have 2 `__m128i`. Each contains 8x `int16_t` (**signed**)

```
__mm128i a = {a0,...,a7}
__mm128i b = {b0,...,b7}
```

I want to multiply 8 elements. The result of each multiply is **`int32_t`** so each register will hold only 4 results:

```
__mm128i c0 = {a0*b0,...,a3*b3}
__mm128i c1 = {a4*b4,...,a7*b7}
```

I did not find such intrinsic.

Answer (score 3):

`SSE2` has a 16-bit "mul_hi" that returns the high half of the product. The high 16-bits and low 16-bits are combined into 32-bits using unpack.

```
    __m128i lo = _mm_mullo_epi16(a, b);
    __m128i hi = _mm_mulhi_epi16(a, b);
    __m128i c0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(lo, hi);
    __m128i c1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(lo, hi);
```

Answer (score 1):

[@aqrit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76328952/multiply-128-bit-vectors-of-signed-16-bit-integers-widening-to-32-bit-elements/76336373#76336373) points out that it's as easy as `pmullw` + `pmulhw`, and unpack lo / hi to combine 16-bit halves of each 32-bit product.  Accept that one.

---

##### Mostly obsolete answer - only useful if odd/even interleaved is useful

(Or perhaps as an alternate building block for an AVX2 version that wants to widen to `__m256i` results - it's non-obvious how to do that efficiently for `__m256i` inputs.  With `__m128i` inputs you should just widen each input to 8x 32-bit with `vpmovzxwd` (`_mm256_cvtepu16_epi32`) and use `_mm256_madd_epi16`.)

x86's only widening 16x16 -> 32-bit SIMD multiply is `pmaddwd`, which horizontally adds pairs of products.  So it's not directly usable, but if one of the products produces zero, then you have a 32-bit product of two signed 16-bit integers within that dword element.

You could unpack (with zero-extension) both inputs (4 shuffles) to feed 2 `pmaddwd` instruction.
Unpacking with zero-extension is cheaper for the high half, since `_mm_unpackhi_epi16` against `_mm_setzero_si128()` is cheaper than manually doing sign extension with an arithmetic right shift, or doing extra work to feed the high half to `_mm_cvtepi16_epi32` (`pmovsxwd`).

You'd only need or want sign extension if you were using `pmulld` (32x32 -> 32-bit multiply), but you want to avoid that since it's slower on Intel CPUs (2 uops per instruction).  https://uops.info/

Multiplying 16-bit signed integers zero-extended to 32-bit with `pmaddwd` is doing `a0*b0 + 0*0` and so on in each element.  If you sign-extended the inputs, you could be doing `a0*b0 + -1*-1`, which is why you need zero-extension if you're going to do this optimization.

---

If unpacking to odd/even works for you, that's more efficient since `0 x garbage = 0` so we only need 2 instructions (plus some register copies) to prepare 2 pairs of inputs, and none of them are shuffles.  (Shifts within 32-bit words like `psrld` would require shifting both inputs to keep the multiplicands lined up correctly.)

```
   __m128i a, b;  // inputs

   __m128i even_mask = _mm_set1_epi32(0x0000FFFF);
   __m128i a_even = _mm_and_si128(a, even_mask);
   __m128i b_odd = _mm_andnot_si128(even_mask, b);  

  // only need to mask one input to each multiply: 0 x garbage = 0
   __m128i prod_even = _mm_madd_epi16(a_even, b);  // { a0*b0, a2*b2, a4*b4, a6*b6 }
   __m128i prod_odd  = _mm_madd_epi16(a, b_odd);   // { a1*b1, a3*b3, a5*b5, a7*b7 }
```

We could just mask `a` both ways; both ways have end up having the same amount of `movdqa` instructions to copy a register, at least in a function that can destroy the input registers holding `a` and `b`.  It does have the fun advantage that whichever input was ready last (in out-of-order exec), the other one had time to already get masked and be ready to exec one of the multiplies.  This is more interesting on old CPUs with only 1/clock throughput for `pmaddwd` (e.g. Intel before Skylake; https://uops.info/).

---

That odd/even product might be a better starting point for what you want, since it only requires 2 more shuffles to interleave `prod_even` and `prod_odd` into `prod_low` and `prod_high`

```
  __m128i prod_low  = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(prod_even, prod_odd); // { a0*b0, a1*b1, a2*b2, a3*b3 }
  __m128i prod_high = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(prod_even, prod_odd);
```

This is 2 bitwise ANDs, 2 `pmaddwd`, and 2x `punpckdq`.

Unpacking both inputs first would have cost 2x `pmovzxwd`, 2x `punpckhwd`, and 2x `pmaddwd`, so all 4 of the non-multiply instructions would be shuffles.  If the surrounding code also needs any shuffles, less pressure on port 5 is good on Intel CPUs with their limited shuffle throughput (especially before Ice Lake).

Using PAND we need a vector constant, but the 4x shuffle way only needs a zeroed register.  I didn't look at the asm to see if one way needs more `movdqa` vector register copies.  The 4x shuffle way might have the advantage there thanks to `pmovzxwd` being a copy-and-shuffle.

The 4x shuffle way looks like this, and is **probably more efficient** unless surrounding code also uses a lot of shuffles that would create a bottleneck on shuffle execution unit throughput.

```
   __m128i a, b;  // inputs

   __m128i a_lo = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(a);
   __m128i b_lo = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(b);

   __m128i a_hi = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(a, _mm_setzero_si128());  // unpack(zero, a) would work equally well but compile less efficiently
   __m128i b_hi = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(b, _mm_setzero_si128());

   __m128i prod_lo = _mm_madd_epi16(a_lo, b_lo);  // { a0*b0, a1*b1, a2*b2, a3*b3 }
   __m128i prod_hi = _mm_madd_epi16(a_hi, b_hi);
```

I put them [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYM9DgDJ4GmADl3ACNMYhAAZg1SAAdUBUJbBmc3Dz04hJsBX38gllDwqItMKyyGIQImYgIU908uYtKkiqqCHMCQsMjohUrq2rSG3tb2vILugEoLVFdiZHYOAFIAJgi/ZDcsAGpFiMde/EEAOgRd7EWNAEEVtYYN123dxzwWFj8CYj8Ts4vrq4A3VB4dBbADuwMYfmAxhixAwrmsxgUCFcVCo9AgphYXGWAA48FsmKQtlicfitsFiaS8QSAFQzAgxVwECa/RYAdgAQr8trzqeSmMZaKgdhEACIk17GZD/AiYJlcABsxnleAiywgTFZEW5V15JOM2JpFKFIt2EsNLGlsvlriVKpiao1wW1ur%2Bl31/IJgoQBPNkqtrgYMSYyAA1r6HXglZqqVKlAQAF5hVBI6N4iATV28gD0Oa2QZD4YgybhxK1YJmtBBoJIYa2mAAjq4xLQAJ5gkq0CnMrZoFiO%2BhbegKBQNtF4ZB4RgEds8vmGskE4LGX2ii1SwuhiN4KMxykBpGYJMptNkzOutl6hdG8mwjCm9eHlhMdDoPeKzWm4kr4XZrZ5jsXKEhotLBNEhJcGBDSEssYHLOWERgREQFivOBq3gS97vmu/qWoar7vqqMY%2BngP6rngl5XL8eb5vwxBbHKvRQoxIpKJgjEIBxTAKCw6EMkyBCLAArJyGgiRK/rYaauxuvqAnMiJnJcBJT7Sb6slsuyaHUQCQI1hCDBQjCcLoAiBDGBgWD/IwmKLsaRIYUuFJUvZ5L0sygmstRXLoV6DY2QwBEKPWeHxseXBRuqEAaKoGjxRoABiyWJVRHo3s5gqYIFT74YY74JOejnZYwwVhmlnpucullvrlUr5QwqAWYVGYlUFL4hT%2B/5XulgECO2Wz%2BJgIJEFsHX1gIHF%2BIJrENqGCBja4tA2DE7YgFsGhbKoWzAFUwRMMAHH%2BuJ15Oca0ltXVVovm%2BH5fm1XWybm%2BYcpyIFgRBTBwcECGEpIYHSISipgYqqF%2BVVWzSVZvJhddhF3Y5K5Wf%2BAEvcBTBQcEMFMEhwQROWwlgcJ5bsmB7KoTsumXIBvIKUJonicJknipDpkqoFmlXDTWx00pKlM2pbNWZz1P5ryxDHrMDAi/O/nScKoIwyz%2BFbuGwpRRqF2BcSUNvtmgGve94Hlpj2Pfb9OPIWD15y2zvrAAtsPGKrO4axAWuMDrQt6zLp28wzqlSWzCsi/JnmKaJ/PMxK6l4A7MvaRwUy0Jwwm8J4HBaKQqCcI4WwKDMcxHasPCkAQmhJ1MYaRLiRxcBEEQAJy4pIyyKo3GjCREkgRMTKccJIvAsBI8WkBnWc5xwvAKCA0Tl5nSekHAsBIP2g5hOQlBr3QXTIMA9cNNZk6YAAatOoIAPIxIwnClzQy1hDPEDBBXpDBH4VRtrfvDv8wxBthfYI2hMDWG/qQfsbBBAXwYGtBepAsDBFcMARwrYZ7cF4FgF8RhxBwPwBLaweAbJoKzpgVQIDmQLFLu8Eor9aB4GCMQT%2BzgsBgI%2BC8b%2BUx0QHQUGfTAl9r4ZzvrIEQYh2BSBkIIRQKh1BwN0A0AwRgQCmGlPoehM9IBTFQDEMoaCAC0F8UK6JfHMU44pVC4kVLoxUkhdH/GWLwVANliCfCwOozMjQQFlHsAwJwLg6heB8aMTo4QGgZESAIAY9RYjxHCQwIJ%2BQuhDBKJ45ofQah%2BMGB4ghAgWjVHieMIYaTIl6GGHkvwHQEkhKmAXWY8w9CgkMAQK%2BBAACSDB%2BAcP0KndOr9J5bQsVYyQO1kDIC2PXOuWwIC4EICQHYJcJi8HnloLMpAuKvi6O46uyxG5HGEuyRU2z26N0kFwXEndG5904IPMevTODT1nmXCuUxl6IBQKgAcO8yAUAgNveg4QRkKP3oqUeR95i8P4TfdBfA6BymIE/F%2BcDf6fzAUi/%2BgDgGgKhRAmc0DYFZwQUglBtBaBoNLpgwwwAcH4rwPgmwRDX6kPIXKMB1D%2B5ZzoQwphGBKGLM%2BMPdBnCDDAB4efK%2BkKhGCBEeIcR/BJFKDUK/XQCFAVKLMKo4IbjNHaKSHogxWwjFVGQKYsU5jLHWNsfY7OTiXGYE1VkrxEAHDFIaD4cpYxEnRMyEkZ1nrYn5I9ZYFJOSikZKiYG7J5Q0n%2BpCRYENqQw1RrdcEiQ1TC51IaA0qB2i2kdIFV0jgacblwL6aawZfZAVjMVEcDQ1bJnTKIAxG4XAFmPIXis6u6ojh4kbuyU57IIiKn2cJHt%2BbrnjwcXciwDylmV3zZa8d2dJ0zpWU4hIdhJBAA%3D) inside functions.  That doesn't test how they'd inline into loops, e.g. the compilers can overwrite the constant they load.  But even with that, the 4x shuffle way is fewer instructions.  Clang "optimizes" the and/andnot to 2x `pblendw`, which is 1 uop for port 5 only on Intel CPUs before Ice Lake.  That might still be better than loading a constant for one call, unlike in a loop.

But anyway, the 4x shuffle way has no extra `movdqa` register-copy instructions, so it costs less front-end bandwidth than the other way that distributes the real work across different ports.

---

@chtz suggested `prod_odd = _mm_sub_epi32(_mm_madd_epi16(a, b), prod_even);` instead of `pandn` before the multiplies.  That has longer critical-path latency, but does save 2 `movdqa` register-copy instructions when we have to compile with AVX. https://godbolt.org/z/7Gxn67d8h

Comment: If you go the even/odd path, you could also do `prod_odd = _mm_sub_epi32(_mm_madd_epi16(a, b), prod_even);` (exchanging one mask with one subtract operation). But probably not really beneficial (I did not investigate if it saves on register management pre-AVX).

Comment: @chtz: Oh that's fun.  `pmaddwd` never saturates or anything like `pmaddubsw` can, only wrapping (signed overflow) for `-8000h^2 * 2` to 80000000 which represents a negative value, but that's fine for a temporary we're going to subtract from.  It does save `movdqa`s - https://godbolt.org/z/7Gxn67d8h shows GCC uses 8 instructions vs. 10 before the stores. Longer critical-path latency for the odd product. (I realized that's one minor advantage of doing `a_even` / `b_odd` - whichever input is ready last, one of the multiplies can start a cycle sooner.  Haswell only has 1 port for `pmaddwd`.)

Comment: I was also thinking about the AVX2 case.  2x `_mm256_cvtepu16_epi32` could feed a single `vpmaddwd ymm`.  But unpacking 32-byte inputs to get 2x 32-byte outputs would suck; avoid that.  odd/even interleaved output is of course still cheap.